# How to overcome the 6 limit of Provider/Consumer with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am currently using `Consumer6<A,B,C,D,E,F>` with the library `Provider` for my Flutter app, and I need to add a couple of `ChangeNotifier`s more (`G`,`H`) for a hypothetical `Consumer8<A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H>` but I just realised that the limit is actually 6. Is there anyway to workaround this limitation?

Comment: How about switching to riverpod ?

Comment: I had a quick look to it. Would it be a painful conversion? Syntax like looks similar

Comment: Nope, It is similar, simple, easier and created by same auther. *Riverpod is inspired by Provider but solves some of it's key issues such as supporting multiple providers of the same type;* you can check [here](https://riverpod.dev/)

Comment: ok thank you, I have opened a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73097374/how-to-migrate-a-consumern-from-provider-to-riverpod-in-flutter as I have some doubts about how to do that migration